# Average of up to X values, in turn averaged with the last value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have time series data from many individuals, where the last entry is rather important for the next entry - but not important enough to stand alone as a predictor for the next entry.

Therefore, I'd like to do this for each entry:

(1) Calculate the average of up to 5 previous entries within the same individual (may be fewer entries, as in my example df)

(2) Grab the last entry of the same individual

(3) Calculate an average of (1) and (2) (equally weighted) as my predicted value for the next entry

My data looks like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[
    '01.01.2020','02.01.2020','03.01.2020','10.01.2020', 
    '01.01.2020','04.02.2020','20.02.2020','21.02.2020', 
    '01.02.2020','10.02.2020','20.02.2020','20.03.2020'],
    'user':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],
    'days_until_next_event':[1,1,7,NaN,3,16,1,NaN,9,10,29,NaN]})
```

The column I'd like to predict is 'days_until_next_event', so for instance for user 3, I'd have the following data:1,9,10,29. The calculation would be: (((1+9+10+29)/4) + 29)/2, with the result of 20.625.

I have a hard time structuring the solution well (beginner!).. Here's where I am at right now:

```
def weightavg(df, group, num_avg):
  average = df.groupby('user').mean()
  latest = ? # Here I'd need to grab the value from the prior row?
  prediction = (average + latest) / 2
```

Expected output for user 1:

```
date         user        days_until_next_event     predicted
01.01.2020   1           1                         NaN
02.01.2020   1           1                         1
03.01.2020   1           7                         1
10.01.2020   1           NaN                       5
```

The 5 in the last row would come from the average of all prior values (1+1+7)/3 = 3, and from the last value 7, averaged. So: (((1+1+7)/3) + 7)/2

Comment: How looks expected output? Maybe the best should be create 2 groups.

Comment: Also in `days_until_next_event` misisng 2 values.

Comment: Thanks for noticing! I added the 2 values for correctness. Give me a minute to manually calculate all the expected output values and add them in a table for clarity.

Comment: I have added an expected output for user1, showing what I am trying to achieve - as well as an explanation below that for how I calculated the predicted column. Thanks @jezrael for helping me improve the question!

Comment: hmm, what is window here? for first row 1, then, 2, then 3 ?

Comment: I want the window to fit 5 entries, but if I have less values for a user I'd calculate the mean with what I got. I.e. if there is only one prior entry, my prediction would end up that the next one is the same. If I have two prior entries 1 and 2, my prediction would end up (1+2)/2 (ie. mean of all prior) + 2 (ie.last entry), divided by 2. So 1.75.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`Series.rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) per groups and add `mean` with last value, last divide by `2`:

```
g = (df.assign(new = df['days_until_next_event'])
       .set_index(['date','days_until_next_event'])
       .groupby('user')['new']
       .rolling(5, min_periods=1))

df1 = (g.mean().add(g.apply(lambda x: x.iat[-1])).div(2)
        .groupby(level=0)
        .shift()
        .reset_index(name='predicted'))
    
print (df1)
    user        date  days_until_next_event  predicted
0      1  01.01.2020                    1.0        NaN
1      1  02.01.2020                    1.0   1.000000
2      1  03.01.2020                    7.0   1.000000
3      1  10.01.2020                    NaN   5.000000
4      2  01.01.2020                    3.0        NaN
5      2  04.02.2020                   16.0   3.000000
6      2  20.02.2020                    1.0  12.750000
7      2  21.02.2020                    NaN   3.833333
8      3  01.02.2020                    9.0        NaN
9      3  10.02.2020                   10.0   9.000000
10     3  20.02.2020                   29.0   9.750000
11     3  20.03.2020                    NaN  22.500000
```

Comment: Thanks! This is great, and does basically what I wanted to achieve. I shifted the results column down one row to achieve the expected output according to my question:               `g = df.set_index('date').groupby('user')['days_until_next_event'].rolling(5, min_periods=1)

s = g.mean().add(g.apply(lambda x: x.iat[-1])).div(2).shift(1)`

Comment: @Galaffer - I think `shift` should be per groups, added to answer.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael for picking that up. I figured the last one would always be a NaN in each user group prior to the shift, but it's definitely better to be careful with those assumptions as you were.. When I adapt to your solution completely, I lose the 'days_until_next_event' column which I'd like to use as a comparison to my prediction column. Is it important that I set the index to date here? (Makes it a little harder to join it back with the original dataframe, although that is maybe not the most elegant solution..)

Comment: @Galaffer - Sorry, a bit busy. Is possible change answer by duplicated `days_until_next_event` to helper colun `new` and for set_index use `['date','days_until_next_event']` ?

Comment: No problem of course! I solved it using .concat now, but I will try this out and paste my final go-to solution for future reference. :)